# Does a syntax-rules expression by itself evaluate to a value in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme, language-specifications, chibi-scheme

In Chibi and CHICKEN, the following `syntax-rules` expression evaluates to a procedure:

```
(syntax-rules () ((_) #f))
```

Is this just an artifact of how these particular implementations are written? The Scheme language specs do not seem to call out `syntax-rules` as being able to evaluate to a value.

---

**Update**

It seems this may depend upon the version of Scheme?

[From the R<sup>6</sup>RS Spec](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_786):

> Semantics: **An instance of syntax-rules evaluates, at macro-expansion time, to a new macro transformer by specifying a sequence of hygienic rewrite rules.** A use of a macro whose keyword is associated with a transformer specified by syntax-rules is matched against the patterns contained in the s, beginning with the leftmost . When a match is found, the macro use is transcribed hygienically according to the template. It is a syntax violation when no match is found.

From the [R<sup>5</sup>RS Spec](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.3.2) and the [R<sup>7</sup>RS Spec](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/wiki/R7RSHomePage):

> Semantics: **An instance of syntax-rules produces a new macro transformer by specifying a sequence of hygienic rewrite rules.** A use of a macro whose keyword is associated with a transformer specified by syntax-rules is matched against the patterns contained in the syntax rules, beginning with the leftmost syntax rule. When a match is found, the macro use is transcribed hygienically according to the template.

Comment: Where do you see the difference? In both specs, it evaluates to a transformer.

Comment: @uselpa - I think you're right, though it's curious that r6rs explicitly states it evaluates whereas r5rs and r7rs are more ambiguous.

Comment: I see you changed the title (and a little bit the sense) of the question... in Scheme a procedure is a value, so yes, `syntax-rules` evaluates to a value, specifically a procedure.

Comment: It never occurred to me that I can write `syntax-rules` that are not within a `define-syntax`. `((syntax-rules () ((_) #f)) #'(x))` actually produces a value in #!racket :)

Comment: @Sylwester - I'm not sure it's a good idea to write code that takes advantage of this, but I agree it's nice to know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[syntax-rules](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/syntax.html#./syntax%3ah2) returns a *transformer*, which is a *procedure* used by the *expander* to transform a syntactic extension into another syntactic extension. See also [here](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/syntax.html).

So no, it's not a special form (this has disappeared from your question in the meantime), and yes, it evaluates to a value, since Scheme has [first-class procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) and therefore procedures are values.

This is Scheme standard behaviour and not an implementation detail of Chicken or Chibi.

Comment: Furthermore, a syntax transformer function is simply... a function from syntax to syntax. Sure, _normally_ you `define-syntax` such functions to be used at compile time by the expander (i.e. for "macros"). However you _can_ define and use such functions at run time (if you're doing something where a syntax-object is a convenient way to represent something). So it totally makes sense that `syntax-rules` (and `syntax-case`, etc.) return a procedure value as, in the question's example.